# Servidor para una aplicación en android studio

Tags: android-studio, apache, servidor

tengo un proyecto en marcha y tengo que crear un servidor para una aplicación en Android Studio.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente : ¿Cual sería la mejor opción para un servidor en una aplicación así?

Lo primero que me viene a la cabeza es configurar un servidor en Apache pero no logro encontrar información de si esta opción es la mejor.

Gracias.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: Importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado. 

No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.